# AngularJS: How to update all values of ng-repeat with one button?

Tags: php, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a ng-repeat, and I have to update "frais" of all values displayed by ng-repeat. this code update only last value. how can I do to update all, please?

file.html

```
<ion-content class="padding" ng-controller="FactureAdminCtrl" ng-repeat = "selectedName in selected">

<ion-list ng-repeat = "selectedName in selected">
          <div class="item item-divider center-text" name="codeE" ng-model="selectedName.CodeEnvoiColis"> {{selectedName.CodeEnvoiColis}} </div>  

          <label class="item item-input">
          <input width="20%" type="text" placeholder="Frais" ng-model="selectedName.FraisFact" style="color:#BA1B1B;"></div> 
          </label>
</ion-list>  

<a class="button button-info" href="#/factureAdmin" ng-click=updateFact(selectedName)> Submit </a>
```

app.js

```
 $scope.updateFact = function(selectedName){ 

           $http.post(  
                "http://localhost/deb/insertFact.php",  
                { 

                'FraisFact':$scope.selectedName.FraisFact,
                'CodeEnvoiColis':$scope.selectedName.CodeEnvoiColis,
              }
           ).success(function(data){  
                alert(data);                                
           });  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use unique model or name for HTML elements 
look at this simple example:

```
<ion-list ng-repeat = "selectedName in selected">
 <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="doc.title[$index]"  name="doc_{{$index}}">
</ion-list>
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't understand your idea, can you explain please!

Comment: Because of same name and same model name  value is override in each repeat  so you have to use different name and model for every repeat.

Comment: Ah ok thank you, I understand your idea , and to implement this I have to add "$index" in html file and .js?

Comment: In Controller, you get an array of title inside the `doc` model in this example

Comment: have I to put this $index in the button and in controller like : updateFact(selectedName,$index) and $scope.updateFact = function(selectedName,$index)!

Comment: example:
`<div data-ng-repeat="document in documents track by $index">
...
</div>`

Comment: I did it, but it blocks the input, I can't insert any value in the input place to update

Comment: Hey See this example http://plnkr.co/edit/WmotdI71CD3fhM21HlAp?p=preview

Comment: `<div class="tagBox" ng-repeat="item in inputs">
    <input ng-model="itemValue[$index]">
</div>`
Then you can get all of your values inside the $scope.itemValue array.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/WmotdI71CD3fhM21HlAp?p=preview this link replace it 
`<input data-comment="{{item.listing_id}}" ng-model="newscopeobj[item.listing_id]" type="text" class="form-control input-sm" /> ` with `<input data-comment="{{item.listing_id}}" ng-model="newscopeobj[$index]" type="text" class="form-control input-sm" /> `

Comment: I try it, and when I implement it in the code I shared, it doesn't work, chen I add $index, it doesn't give me the possibility to write in input.

Comment: Can you please post your code so I will figure out it, or you can write into plunkr.

Comment: @SalamSalam if you are satisfied with my answer make it correct and vote up

Answer (score 0):

```
    <ion-content class="padding" ng-controller="FactureAdminCtrl"  ng-repeat = "selectedName in selected">   
    <ion-list ng-repeat = "selectedName in selected track by $index">
              <div class="item item-divider center-text" name="codeE" ng-model="selectedName.CodeEnvoiColis" > {{selectedName.CodeEnvoiColis}} </div>

              <label class="item item-input">
              <input width="20%" type="text" placeholder="Frais" data-comment= "selectedName.FraisFact" ng-model="FraisFact[$index]" name="FraisFact{{$index}}" style="color:#BA1B1B;"></div> 

              </label>
    </ion-list>
<a class="button button-info" href="#/factureAdmin" ng-click=insertFact(selectedName)> Ajouter </a>
```